# Add instance metadata to an already running gcp compute instance with terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I already have a vm instance running in GCP.Is there a way we can add custom metadata to it using terraform. Terraform has a resource to add custom metadata to a project but not a instance.

I tried to update it by using the `google_compute_instance` resource by setting the `lifecycle.prevent_destroy = true` but that does not seem the correct way.

```
data "google_compute_instance" "instance" {
  name    = var.instance_name
  project = var.project_id
  zone    = var.zone
}


resource "google_compute_instance" "instance" {
  name         = data.google_compute_instance.instance.name
  machine_type = data.google_compute_instance.instance.machine_type
  project = var.project_id
  zone = var.zone
 
# ... rest of the config

  metadata = {
    foo = "bar"
  }
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}
```

But I get an error saying `instance already exists` which suggests that it is trying to create a new one but not update.

Comment: Did you previously create the VM with terraform?

Comment: No, I created it through gcloud.

Comment: If your resource is not managed by terraform, terraform does not know that the resource exist. And when it tries to create it, it fail because of duplicated name. The VPGCLOUD answer points out to the right direction: Import your current VM instance in the terraform state. And then, update the terraform and apply it. It should work

Comment: For Terraform, Compute instance metadata is declared when you create a VM. You can then modify the HCL metadata section to update the VM later. However, I think you must shut down the VM to make metadata changes using Terraform. Since you created the VM outside of Terraform, be very careful importing an existing VM. Make sure you have a valid verified backup because a mistake can result in deleting the VM. Test in a throw-away project first.

Comment: If you are not comfortable with the risks of importing into Terraform, use the CLI to update instance metadata. See this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/setting-custom-metadata#set_metadata_running_vm). Depending on the metadata that you are changing, you might need to restart the VM to effect changes.

Comment: GUILLAUME
I am still facing the same issue even after using the import block. After importing I can see the instance in my terraform.tfstate file. But when I run terraform apply I am still facing the same issue where it is trying to create a new one. Even while it is planning I can see Plan: 1 to import, 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy. where I think it should be 0 to add, 1 to change.

Comment: Thanks GUILLAUME & JOHN, your explanation helped me understand better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the data block you need an import block (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#import), otherwise Terraform would try to create it.

Comment: I am still facing the same issue even after using the import block. After importing I can see the instance in my terraform.tfstate file. But when I run `terraform apply` I am still facing the same issue where it is trying to create a new one. Even while it is planning I can see `Plan: 1 to import, 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.` where I think it should be `0 to add, 1 to change`.

Comment: And metadata = {     foo = "bar"   } is the new data you want to change? And the VM doesn't have it yet?

Comment: yes, the VM does not have it yet.

Comment: VPGCLOUD
My bad, this approach worked. I was making a error while setting the new value for metadata and hence I was getting the following error.